# Подключение разных библиотек: получить список функций и их параметры

Tags: c++

Необходимо сделать программу которая получает список функций их названия, описание, количество и тип аргументов из определенных dll-ок. И что бы была возможность любую функцию вызвать. Это все на c++.

1. Как это сделать?
2. Есть ли готовое решение?
3. Советы и предложения.

Структура программы например такая:

```
+ root
    - prog.exe
    - func1.dll # эти библиотеки обновляются
    - func2.dll #  и появляется новый 
    - func3.dll #   функционал.
```

Я хочу по мере развития библиотек заменять dll'ки(названия файлов не менять), но GUI приложение (prog.exe) не изменять.
Как насчет реализовать в каждой библиотеки одну функцию `getListFuncs()`, которая будет возвращать список функций и их прототипы (пока не знаю как красиво такое сделать). Всегда вызывать эту функцию из prog.exe и составлять список возможных вызовов функций.
**UDP:** Мне хочется узнать, есть ли что то подобное (раз тему закрыли, видимо нет). И второе: какие механизмы использовать для сохранения типа, что бы можно было восстановить. Создал тестовый проект, который работает в лоб. Хочу совет, возможно использование c++11/14 или decltype.

```
enum Types {
    __int_t,
    __string_t,
    __double_t,
    // more
}

struct funcStruct {
    Types fReturn;
    std::list<Types> args;
    std::string name;
    std::string description;
}

std::list<funcStruct> getListFuncs();  // эта ф-ция реализована в библиотеке

int main() {
    auto listFuncs = getListFuncs();
    for (auto fStruct : listFuncs) {
        std::cout << fStruct.name << std::endl;
        std::cout << fStruct.description << std::endl;
        if (fStruct.fReturn == __int_t) {
            if (fStruct.args.lenght() == 1) {
                if (fStruct.args.at(0) == __int_t) {
                    int (*otrF)(3); // для примера
                }
                if (fStruct.args.at(0) == __string_t) {
                    int (*otrF)("str"); // для примера
                }
                if (fStruct.args.at(0) == __duoble_t) {
                    int (*otrF)(3.14); // для примера
                }
            } else if (fStruct.args.lenght() == 2) {
                // ...
            } // ...
        } else if (fStruct.fReturn == __string_t) {
            // ...
        } // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: под виндой манипуляции с dll осуществляются с помощью функций из заголовочного файла libloaderapi.h(https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/)

Comment: "*Советы и предложения*" - поставить более реалистичную задачу? В неуправляемых DLL информация о типах аргументов для функций, экспортируемых через EXTERN "C" просто не хранится; а для экспортируемых с декорированным именем хоть и хранится, но формат полностью зависит от компилятора, стандарта нет.

Comment: Передача через границы DLL std::list и std::string - уже плохо. Их внутреннее устройство также специфично для конкретного компилятора. Хотите переносимое решение - на границе должны быть только типы C. Проще всего, думаю, паковать все хозяйство в какой-нибудь XML/JSON и передавать как char *. Как (и зачем) сюда впихивать c++11/14, я даже не знаю.

Comment: впихивать с++11/14 для того, что бы не перебирать все возможные типы данных, а прямо хранить и сразу использовать тип (не знаю такое можно сделать). Избавиться от `enum Types`

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight на счет `string & list`: не уж то все скомпилированные библиотеки возвращают типы С? или они предоставляют несколько версий своих библиотек, скомпилированных с помощью разных компиляторов?

Comment: @KtoTo На практике большинство библиотек на С++ поставляются в виде исходного кода или как набор заголовочных файлов. "Скомпилированные библиотеки" в С++ не очень полезны, так как не дают возможность воспользоваться функционалом шаблонов. Но если библиотека должна быть скомпилированной то да, для нее необходимо делать С-интерфейс: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL

Comment: можно привести пример. Нужно платформонезависимое решение

Comment: В boost есть библиотека boost.DLL. Библиотека скрывает платформозависимый код и предоставляет упрощённый интерфейс. Она ещё развивается, но использовать как базу для создания плагинов уже можно. Не знаю почему никто её не упомянул.

Comment: Вообще это вопрос про метаданные для C++. Собственно, C++ я не знаю, но метаданные для него делают с помощью самописных костылей, в лучших традициях. Ну что еще? Еще статья с rsdn в результате гуглинга: https://www.rsdn.org/article/xml/xmlcpp.xml. Вряд ли, конечно, поможет, но все-таки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть COM-библиотека, изюминкой которой является IDispatch интерфейс. Библиотека позволяет создавать классы, доступ к которым осуществляется через детерминированый интерфейс-посредник с небольшим числом (около 10-20) методов, т.е подключив обьект - можно узнать перечень свойств и методов этого обьекта и выполнить методы или прочесть/записать его свойства. Вопрос довольно обширный, я его рассмотрю весьма поверхносно.

Основа

```
   public class MyClass: public IDispatch
{
    // ...

    // implementing IDualInterface

    ITypeInfo* m_pTypeInfo // должен содержать ссылку на "информацию" ITypeLib::GetTypeInfoOfGuid for the GUID of IDualInterface

    // IDispatch
    STDMETHODIMP GetTypeInfoCount(UINT* pctinfo)
    {
        *pctinfo = 1;
        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP GetTypeInfo(UINT itinfo, LCID lcid, ITypeInfo** pptinfo)
    { // Запрос "справочника"
        if (0 != itinfo)
            return E_INVALIDARG;
        (*pptinfo = m_pTypeInfo)->AddRef();
        return S_OK;
    }

    STDMETHODIMP GetIDsOfNames(REFIID riid, LPOLESTR* rgszNames, UINT cNames, LCID lcid, DISPID* rgdispid)
    {
        // Преобразует массив имен rgszNames в массив rgdispid, для Invoke
        return m_pTypeInfo->GetIDsOfNames(rgszNames, cNames, rgdispid);
    }

    STDMETHODIMP Invoke(DISPID dispidMember, REFIID riid, LCID lcid, WORD wFlags, DISPPARAMS* pdispparams, VARIANT* pvarResult, EXCEPINFO* pexcepinfo, UINT* puArgErr)
    {
        // Собственно процедура для имплементации
        // Тут можно делать Get Put и Execute для членов класса с конкретным dispid
    }
}
```

Так же нужно реализовать интерфейс ITypeInfo и IUnknown.

Один из вариантов - Microsoft и Borland продукты имеют конструкторы, которые упрощают написание COM интерфейсов и делают автоматическое связывание обычных методов с COM-интерфейсом.

Незаригестрированый интерфейс может участвовать в программе, регистрация интерфейса даёт возможность публично его использовать в других программах, при использование COM в рамках одной программы регистрацию не считаю обязательной, но нужно понимать, что и экземпляр класса нужно создавать через new, а не через CoCreateInstance (который создаёт зарегистрированые интерфейсы). Так же такие интерфейсы можно передавать в зарегистрированых обьектах, например в виндовой ScriptControl (т.е. в COM-JavaScript).

Больше можно почитать по ссылкам:

http://studfiles.net/preview/397622/page:55/
http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-idispatch
http://rsdn.org/article/com/introcom.xml
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19253471/implement-com-idispatch-without-atl
http://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/build/dlls-in-visual-cpp

Answer (score 1):

Одним из вариантов решения, это будет написания системы плагинов.

Плагин будет делать все сам, а вы просто будете вызывать у него определенный метод, или функцию.

К примеру, ваша библиотека первой версии что-то делала `так`, но когда вы решили обновить плагин, то она стала делать `вот так`. при этом вам ничего с главным приложением делать не потребуется, т.к. плагин будет иметь несколько методов, например:

```
// Start
PuginInstance instance = PluginInit(...)

...

PluginDoSomething(...)

...

// End
PluginCleanup(instance);
```

Ответ **чисто теоретический**, и не имеет никакой реализации или побуждений **ТС** поступать именно так.

*Примерно так работает проигрыватель **VLC**, написанный на [c](/questions/tagged/c), но использующий библиотеки **Qt** написанные на [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) как модуль интерфейса.*

Comment: Спасибо большое! то что нужно. через 3 дня приму ответ